# Работа со строками в С

Tags: c, строки

Помогите решить задачу.  
Нужно определить количество слов, входящих в обе введённые строки (желательно с кодом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно только количество слов (с учетом возможных повторов), то посчитайте количество пробелов. Правда, перед этим нужно обрезать лишние пробелы в конце и в начале строки (trim), убрать двойные пробелы и пробелы перед знаками препинания (или добавить недостающие после знаков, как здесь: "текст,для ,примера").

Если нужны слова, которые входят и в первую, и во вторую строки: разбейте первую строку по пробелам, удалите знаки препинания и ищите вхождение во вторую строку (subsrtr).

Comment: Лучше посчитать количество пробелов после символов str[i] && str[i + 1]